# Differentiate apps in main method

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I'm wondering how can i differentiate 2 apps in my main method. I have 2 projects which use same backend but different frontend.They use different configurations since i can't read the appsettings file in main method, is there another way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very general so here's a general answer:

Put all of the "common" code in library projects and have two different "launcher" porjects that reference these libraries. Each launcher app (or site since you mentioned MVC) will have its own separate config file.

I would not try to "cleverly" build combine two different apps in one assembly and try to toggle between them.